# Not able to read data from Redshift using Spark-Scala

Tags: scala, authentication, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I am trying to read data from Amazon Redshift, but getting below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: You must specify a method for authenticating Redshift's connection to S3 (aws_iam_role, forward_spark_s3_credentials, or temporary_aws_*. For a discussion of the differences between these options, please see the README.
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
at com.databricks.spark.redshift.Parameters$MergedParameters.<init>(Parameters.scala:91)
at com.databricks.spark.redshift.Parameters$.mergeParameters(Parameters.scala:83)
at com.databricks.spark.redshift.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:330)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
```

Using below code to read data :

```
 val session = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("POC")
    .getOrCreate()

  session.conf.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "<access_key>")
  session.conf.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "<secret-key>")

  val eventsDF = session.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
    .option("url","<jdbc_url>" )
    .option("dbtable", "test.account")
    .option("tempdir", "s3n://testBucket/data")
    .load()
  eventsDF.show()
```

build.sbt :

```
name:= "Redshift_read"

scalaVersion:= "2.11.8"

version := "1.0"

val sparkVersion = "2.1.0"

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
      "com.databricks" %% "spark-redshift" % "3.0.0-preview1",
      "com.amazonaws"     %   "aws-java-sdk"    % "1.11.0"
    )
```

Can anyone help me out, what am i missing ? I have already provided access key and secret key in spark but still it is throwing error.

Comment: Isn't `fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId`, etc. a part of SparkContext configuration rather than that of SparkSession?

Comment: You are right. When i set sparkcontext configuration,  it worked. Thanks Grant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working just by defining the SparkContext setting instead of SparkSession for S3 keys.

Replace :

```
session.conf.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "<access_key>")
session.conf.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "<secret-key>")
```

with :

```
session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId,"<access_key>")
session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "<secret_key>")
```

Also add below dependency in build.sbt :

```
resolvers += "redshift" at "http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release"

    "com.amazon.redshift" % "redshift-jdbc42" % "1.2.1.1001"
```